# In Visual Studio C++, How to quickly find necessary header files?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, header-files

I know a fair amount of Java and Eclipse IDE, but am new to Visual Studio and C++.  In Eclipse/Java, if you use a predefined class, Eclipse helpfully suggests the appropriate header file to include for the code to compile.  Wondering if Visual Studio has similar functionality.
For example every time I use a code sample from the web, I spend a lot of time Googling which header files to include so the code will compile.  My current challenge:  I'm writing a small utility that reads filenames in a directory into an array for batch renaming.  For this, I'm using following code fragment:

```
DIR* dir;
struct dirent* dirEntry;
dirEntry = readdir(dir);
```

Visual Studio is giving the error message: "DIR" is unidentified.  "readdir" is unidentified.
Is there an efficient way to locate the appropriate header files for C++ code fragments to resolve error messages like these?  Thanks.

Comment: Looks like the Keebler elves at Microsoft have answered your wishes: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c-productivity-improvements-in-visual-studio-2019-preview-2/

Comment: @Eljay: This is the Exact functionality I'm looking for, but is not available in my IDE.  I'm using the latest version: VS Community 2019 v16.3.10.

Comment: Just to note, speaking generally, languages like C#/Java/etc are easier to provide this feature for. C++ on the other hand is more complicate from the perspective of the compiler (which includes compiling enough of a header to determine what it contains) which is presumably part of why a feature like this hasn't been provided until now.

Comment: That functionality should have been available since VS 2019 v16.0, unless it is a feature that is only in the Professional version.  (I don't know where to find a detailed feature list of Professional or Enterprise features that are not in the Community edition.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this feature in vs2019 community 16.3.6 and it works. When you hover the mouse at the location of an error, you can see an error light bulb. And click the drop-down arrow next to the error bulb to add missing #include.

[image]

You can also press **Alt+Enter**.

Comment: Ahhh, it seems to function with limited scope.  I commented-out <iostream>, and yes, Visual Studio did suggest including it back.  But try it on the code fragment I posted in my question and it doesn't work.  All I'm trying to do is read filenames into an array so the names can be manipulated in a loop.

Comment: I found part of the problem--dirent is a struct in Linux.  Not available in Windows.  So my sample code fragment will not work on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in some answers above, Visual Studio has started offering some suggestions for header files.  But as of this writing, some VS suggestions lead to other error messages.  E.g. I just used `getline()`. VS gave error message: Identifier "getline" is unidentified.  It suggested I add `using namespace std::basic_istream;` to my code.  But this was not applicable to my code and produced additional error messages.
After stumbling around, I found a very simple solution: Visit the C++ reference website.  There I searched for `getline` and found the header information at the following link: [getline()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).  To fix the error, I needed to `#include <string>`.